# Birt Global Integer

Tags: report, global-variables, birt

I have a Birt Report which read some stuff from a database.
After that i want to increment a global Integer for every Detailrow that is loaded.
So far i have initialized a global Integer with the following lines:

```
importPackage(Packages.java.lang);
reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable("minTotalPlus", new Integer(0));
```

After that i added the following line into a field in my detail row:

```
reportContext.setGlobalVariable("minTotalPlus",  new Integer reportContext.getGlobalVariable("minTotalPlus")) + 1);
```

When i preview the report i get an "java.lang.NumberFormatException: null" which means that the global variable is null. Why is that so? How could I fix that?

Comment: In your second snippet of code above, you call "setGlobalVariable".  This is not a valid BIRT scripting method.  Is this an error in the post or possibly an error on the report contributing to the issues you are seeing.  I have some ideas here but I wanted to clear tht up before proceeding.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your answer. I found out that you can define a global variable very easily by just adding "minTotalPlus = new Integer(0);" to the initialize event of your report. So I dont need the code above anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Dont' declare variables like that in the initialize method 
declare the like the following

```
materiales=0;
tools=0;
```

then in the fetch method
use the following

```
tools++;
```

...etc.